# Checking in folder working copy breaks children working copies

Tags: plone

Plone 4.1.5
plone.app.iterate 2.1.5

To see the behavior:

1. Create a folder ('foo')
2. Create a page ('bar') within folder 'foo'
3. Checkout a working copy ('copy_of_bar') of page 'bar'
4. Checkout a working copy ('copy_of_foo') of folder 'foo'
5. Checkin 'copy_of_foo'

Now, 'bar' is still locked but no longer shows the info viewlet linking to the working copy. 'copy_of_bar' appears to have become a normal (non-wc) page. Interestingly, this break doesn't occur if you checkout the page after checking out the folder (ie. checkout 'bar' within 'copy_of_foo').

Looks like it's breaking on the folder checkout. If you look at the pages in 'copy_of_foo', 'copy_of_bar' is already acting like a non-wc page.

Comment: Sounds like a bug indeed; have you tried reporting it to the Plone bugtracker?

Comment: @MartijnPieters reported [#13431](https://dev.plone.org/ticket/13431)